# Check for intersection of raster and vector in R

Tags: raster, r, intersection, sf

I have a `rasterstack` and a vector-geometry (`sf`-object). The raster's values are either `ǸA` or some integer. I would like to check if the raster (in the best case just as a binary response) has any intersection with the shape in the points that are non-`NA` in the raster. And I don't want to use the bounding box of the raster.
I thought about polygonzing the raster where the values are not `NA`. But this seems a lot of effort and space. I'm not asking for any specific code, but maybe an approach that could be used in `R`

Comment: Can you do `extract(raster, polygons)` and if you get all NA values then its not intersecting any data values in your raster. That will test against the polygon even clipping a tiny part of a raster cell.

Comment: great idea, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Spacedman won't this test against raster cell centroids only?

Comment: The default for extract(raster, polygons) has `small=TRUE` which returns samples for any intersection of the polygon with a cell, even partial. You can add `weights=TRUE` to get the area clipped.

Comment: @Spacedman FWIW, here's a simple example where `small=TRUE` misses an intersection https://gist.github.com/dbaston/3f21c3c399021f3b5aace12e4f09a495

Comment: I'd say that's a bug. A very similar triangle with more vertices does extract a value from that raster. Please report it.

Comment: https://github.com/rspatial/raster/issues/100

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this naive question, but I still struggle to find a good way... What does the `length` of the list returned by `raster::extract(ras, vec)` tell me? I'm a little confused about that

Answer (score 3):

You can use `extract` from the `raster` package to get a list of overlapping raster and polygon values, and then can check the extracted values - if there are any NAs then the sum of the values will be NA:

Reproducible example, with a raster half integer 1s and half NAs:

```
library(sf)
library(raster)

r <-
  raster(
    nrows = 50, ncols = 50,
    xmn = 0, xmx = 5, ymn = 0, ymx = 5,
    crs = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"),
    vals = c(rep(1, 1250), rep(NA, 1250))
  )


# Polygon without overlap of NA area:
p1 <-
  data.frame(id = 1, wkt = 'POLYGON((2 3, 2.5 3, 2.5 3.5, 2 3.5, 2 3))')
p1 <- st_as_sf(p1, wkt = 'wkt', crs = 4326)

sum(unlist(extract(r, p1))) # Result [1] 25

# Polygon totally overlapping with NA area:
p2 <-
  data.frame(id = 1, wkt = 'POLYGON((0 0, 0 0.5, 0.5 0.5, 0.5 0, 0 0))')
p2 <- st_as_sf(p2, wkt = 'wkt', crs = 4326)

sum(unlist(extract(r, p2))) # Result [1] NA
```

Comment: sorry a little late, but do you know the `velox`-package? It's amazing for exactly this task of extracting raster-values based on some vector-data. It's lightning fast;)

Comment: I wasn't aware of it - if it provides a better solution than this answer, go ahead and answer the question yourself with a good code example!

Answer (score 3):

I decided to go the following way. There is a package called `velox` which does extraction of raster values based on polygons really fast. For some reason it worked better for me using `sp` than `sf`-objects. So here's more or less what I did:

```
rast.norm = raster(rasts[i]) # load it first as RasterLayer
rast.trim = trim(rast.norm) # trim that raster to delete outer NAs
shape.crp = st_crop(shape, rast.trim) 
shape.sp = sf::as_Spatial(shape.crp)
rast.vx = velox(rast.trim) # load runout raster as velox raster
ex.vx = rast.vx$extract(shape.sp) 
matr = do.call(rbind, ex.vx) # rowbind all matrices 
print(sum(matr[,1][!is.na(matr[,1])]))
```

If the sum is 0 or the crop-step doesn't work it means there is no intersection. I think maybe isn't the fastest way, but for me it worked.

Comment: How did it work better for you?

Comment: It was faster I guess. But actually that's just my own specific solution to the  problem at hand. I don't know if it's "better" than any other solution